# Vagrant, Symfony, chmod permit

Tags: linux, symfony, vagrant, puppet, puphpet

Host: ubuntu latest x64
vagrant 1.7.2
Configuration (puphpet)
Yaml config:

```
vagrantfile:
    target: local
    vm:
        box: puphpet/debian75-x64
        box_url: puphpet/debian75-x64
        hostname: developer
        memory: '1024'
        cpus: '1'
        chosen_provider: virtualbox
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.56.2
            forwarded_port:
                vflnp_o959ky5yk541:
                    host: '8592'
                    guest: '22'
        post_up_message: ''
        provider:
            virtualbox:
                modifyvm:
                    natdnshostresolver1: on
                showgui: '0'
            vmware:
                numvcpus: 1
            parallels:
                cpus: 1
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: site.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder:
            vflsf_xjd88rswg95m:
                source: ../Presta/www
                target: /var/www/presta
                sync_type: nfs
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
                # owner: www-data
                # group: www-data
            vflsf_htm6wvj2khq1:
                source: '../Karty_Pracy/www'
                target: /var/www/worksheets
                sync_type: nfs
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
                # owner: www-user
                # group: www-data
            vfawf_htsadas3khq1:
                source: '../Magazyn/www'
                target: /var/www/warehouse
                sync_type: nfs
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
                # owner: www-user
                # group: www-data
                # map_uid: 0
                # map_gid: 0    
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: null
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    install: '1'
    packages:
        - htop
        - zsh
        - git
        - mc
        - unzip
        - zip
        - unrar
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        nxv_nwz3nbjvoere:
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome
            listen_port: '80'
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_port: '443'
            ssl_protocols: ''
            ssl_ciphers: ''
            rewrite_to_https: '1'
            spdy: '1'
            locations:
                nxvl_nfl6ndp0s1h1:
                    location: /
                    autoindex: off
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: ''
                    fastcgi_index: ''
                    fastcgi_split_path: ''
                nxvl_oy9dxc91j6zf:
                    location: '~ \.php$'
                    autoindex: off
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: index.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename'
                        - 'APP_ENV dev'
    proxies: {  }
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - proxy_fcgi
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        presta:
            servername: presta.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.presta.dev
            docroot: /var/www/presta
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_hycw94gg20u6:
                    path: /var/www/presta
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_0yv1i2x4gd9j:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: ''
                            provider: filesmatch
                    provider: directory
        worksheets:
            servername: worksheets.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.worksheets.dev
            docroot: /var/www/worksheets/web
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - APP_ENV_dev
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_88fsnn8di1c5:
                    path: /var/www/worksheets/web
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_ro0fe2wzpcad:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: ''
                            provider: filesmatch
                    provider: directory
        warehouse:
            servername: warehouse.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.warehouse.dev
            docroot: /var/www/warehouse/web
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - APP_ENV_dev
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_88fsnn8diaw5:
                    path: /var/www/warehouse/web
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_ro0fe2wzpcad:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: ''
                            provider: filesmatch
                    provider: directory        
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '56'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
            - curl
            - cgi
            - gd
            - imagick
            - mysql
            - mysqlnd
            - sqlite
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_tl7whm0zxnuj:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
xdebug:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '1'
        xdebug.idekey: PHPStorm
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
blackfire:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        server_id: ''
        server_token: ''
        agent:
            http_proxy: ''
            https_proxy: ''
            log_file: stderr
            log_level: '1'
        php:
            agent_timeout: '0.25'
            log_file: ''
            log_level: '1'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: v0.19.0
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 6.3.0
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions: {  }
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '1'
    npm_packages:
        - bower
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings: {  }
    server_ini:
        hhvm.server.host: 127.0.0.1
        hhvm.server.port: '9000'
        hhvm.log.use_log_file: '1'
        hhvm.log.file: /var/log/hhvm/error.log
    php_ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        date.timezone: UTC
mysql:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '5.6'
        root_password: presta
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: '1'
    users:
        mysqlnu_9vxflivbus3n:
            name: presta
            password: presta
        mysqlnu_uvdxcu9kcnmf:
            name: worksheets
            password: worksheets
        mysqlnu_9vxfladvbus3n:
            name: warehouse
            password: warehouse
    databases:
        mysqlnd_0eud6qyvgftl:
            name: presta
            sql: ''
        mysqlnd_310bhtyb1ezk:
            name: worksheets
            sql: ''
        mysqlnd_310bhaddsdasdw:
            name: warehouse
            sql: ''    
    grants:
        mysqlng_er3ka00fh3xm:
            user: presta
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
        mysqlng_l0g86y9hymun:
            user: worksheets
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
        mysqlng_l0asdy9hymun:
            user: warehouse
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        global:
            encoding: UTF8
            version: '9.3'
        server:
            postgres_password: '123'
    databases: {  }
    users: {  }
    grants: {  }
    adminer: 0
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        bind_ip: 127.0.0.1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
sqlite:
    install: '1'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mailcatcher:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default
        from_email_method: headers
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '13000'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
    users: {  }
    vhosts: {  }
    plugins: {  }
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 1.4.1
        java_install: true
solr:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 4.10.2
        port: '8984'
```

Issue:

> $ php app/console fos:user:change-password admin admin
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]     Warning:
>   chmod(): Operation not permitted
>
> fos:user:change-password

On web issue expects too.
Permissions looks good:

```
$ ls -la
total 224
drwxrwxrwx 12 www-data www-data   4096 Jul  2 12:57 ./
drwxrwxr-x  6 root     www-data   4096 Jul  3 06:39 ../
drwxrwxrwx  6 www-data www-data   4096 Jul  2 13:26 app/
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data   4096 Jun 26 10:51 bin/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data    362 Jul  2 12:57 bower.json*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data     35 Jul  2 12:57 .bowerrc*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   3340 Jul  2 12:57 composer.json*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data 154557 Jul  2 09:50 composer.lock*
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data   4096 Jul  2 12:57 doc/
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data   4096 Jul  2 10:25 files/
drwxrwxrwx  8 www-data www-data   4096 Jul  3 06:47 .git/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data    164 Jul  2 12:57 .gitignore*
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data   4096 Jul  3 06:26 .idea/
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data   4096 Jul  2 12:57 src/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data    595 Jul  2 12:57 sync.sh*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data    245 Jul  2 12:57 TODO*
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data   4096 Jul  2 10:54 var/
drwxrwxrwx 37 www-data www-data   4096 Jul  2 09:59 vendor/
drwxrwxrwx 10 www-data www-data   4096 Jul  2 13:01 web/
```

So, this looks like bad mounting nfs(can't use chmod) How to solve this?

Comment: The cheap workaround would be to mount NFS with the `norootsquash` option. Requires careful risk assessment, though.

Comment: Where i must add this option?

Answer (score 0):

> So, this looks like bad mounting nfs(can't use chmod) How to solve this?

You must treat the virtual box-side of a sync'ed folder as 'read-only.'  Run commands which modify the contents of a sync'ed folder instead on the host computer itself (your Mac); for example, `php composer.phar install`.  Remote OS's (virtual machines) will cause **"Operation not permitted"** errors when they try to change files originating on the host operating system.

For reference, see my answer to a similar question at this link:

[The Operation not permitted problem...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157780/recurring-vagrant-error-operation-not-permitted-on-action-create-on-an-nfs-re/31629110#31629110)

There's another answer that discusses the importance of treating `synced_folder`s as read-only file locations on your Virtual Machines.

[How to use vagrant on multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063686/how-to-use-vagrant-on-multiple-projects/31547882#31547882)

Comment: If someone has to run PHP (PHP composer.phar install) on the host system, then why to use a virtual-box at all?

Answer (score 0):

You must run this command `fos:user:change-password` from `/vagrant` folder (not from `/var/www/presta`)

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to [this](https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/1756) issue. 
The solution is:

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-bindfs
vagrant reload
```

Hope it helps.