# Vagrant failing on mounting NFS due to MacOS Catalina beta update

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox, macos-catalina

I recently updated to MacOS Catalina and began some development from it. The problem is when I "vagrant up" on the terminal, NFS shared folders fail to mount and I am forced to use rsync. However, rsync does not let me use git seamlessly for my work. The reason this is happening I figured out was because the new MacOS created multiple volumes so vagrant is confused where the root of the file in Documents may be:
[MacOS Disk Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7p3i.png)

Is there some way to set the root to something different in the /etc/exports file without it replacing the exports file on every vagrant up? The root is sadly no longer just "/..." it is "System/Volumes/Data/..." in this new MacOS but there is a copy of everything on "/" so vagrant is confused on which to use as the root.

I am repeatedly getting this error message when trying to *vagrant up*:
[Terminal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2z61.png)

Comment: You may want to consider posting this on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: have you figured it out?

Comment: @pasevin the only option is to use rsync-auto on a separate terminal window. I had to downgrade my entire macOS back to mojave as many applications were not supported on Catalina.

Comment: Thanks, I've disabled ```config.vm.synced_folder type: "nfs"``` for now, it works, but provisioning is super slow.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have figured out the solution after tinkering. For me, I had to update everything including vagrant (v2.2.6) and virtual box.

Then, in MacOS Catalina, navigate to System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Privacy → Full Disk Access and press '+' then Command-Shift-G and enter the `/sbin` directory and find the `nfsd` file and add that to Full Disk Access.

Then sudo nano to your `/etc/exports` and delete everything in the file and vagrant up should work flawlessly!

Comment: If you're here because of the Catalina update, and you already had the last Vagrant bin installed on your system, this does the trick!

For me it was granting nfsd write access to the disk

Comment: I had to move my project from ~/Documents to a different location

Comment: When I try to delete everything from the host file `/etc/exports`, it says that I don't own it and to duplicate it. So, I cannot delete everything from it.

Comment: @nbro this solution is probably outdated. However, I would try editing the file with sudo and if using a 3rd party terminal (such as iTerm), giving it full disk access.

Answer (score 2):

For me this was the solution:
https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10961#issuecomment-526132132

"workaround is to add /System/Volumes/Data/... to your paths in VagrantFile and /etc/exports"

Comment: What does to `...to your paths in VagrantFile and /etc/exports` mean? "paths in Vagrantfile?

Answer (score 2):

For me the workaround suggested in the github issue (https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10961#issuecomment-526132132) took the following form, so it does not break non-Catalina hosts:

```
nfsPath = "."
if Dir.exist?("/System/Volumes/Data")
    nfsPath = "/System/Volumes/Data" + Dir.pwd
end
config.vm.synced_folder nfsPath, "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
```

This still requires you to remove existing nfs exports from `/etc/exports`, or vagrant will complain about a mismatch between what's in the `/etc/exports` file vs what is configured in `Vagrantfile`.

Comment: I had to move my project from ~/Documents to a different location